# Is there a simple way to ensure .well items have the same height and width regardless of screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three `.well` items on my homepage, and I don't want to fill them with content just to ensure they size correctly on every screen. Ideally I'd like a CSS solution that can specify their height and width match each other regardless of which screen they are being displayed on (and also that they stack correctly when the window shrinks.

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */ 
#benefit-box-1 {
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#benefit-box {
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#benefit-box-3 {
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#benefit-row-2 {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.icon-div {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: centre;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="benefit-row">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box-1">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>Collaborate in your sales meetings.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-map-signs fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>Direct your team to the best deals</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box-3">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-filter fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>Trust your pipeline forecast</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="benefit-row-2">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box-1">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>Helps you target the right contacts</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>In-built sales training</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="benefit-box-3">
      <div class="well">
        <div class="icon-div">
          <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-4x"></i>
          <h1>Smash your sales targets</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a bootply here: [My attempts](http://www.bootply.com/wpCipP1Jq3)

Comment: What can't you just specify the `width` and the `height` using pixels (for example).

Comment: Will that be responsive when re-sizing (on e.g. a small tablet or phone)? I thought the point in using Bootstrap was to make use of their responisveness to various screen sizes.

Comment: I didn't understand you correctly.. If I understand you correctly you want that the height and the width of all `.well` will be the same in each device. If to one of them has more content all the rest will have a space. Right? Do you want to keep them in the different rows?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. I want them to behave like other bootstrap elements, so they behave in a responsive manner on smaller devices (e.g. stacked on an iPhone but as a row of three on a laptop). I want them to all have the same width and height (regardless of their contents) on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by dropping the wells/bootstrap standard responsive behaviour and adopting some of my own using the Flex methods. If anyone is interested here's the bootply: [Flex CSS classes to make responsive pages](http://www.bootply.com/rWi7HreW0F)

I used the info present [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in order to make this work - standard behaviour on my boxes is to have 33% of the screen width on large devices, 50% on medium devices and 100% on small devices. Works a charm.

From what I can tell it's not going to be very useful on older browsers (I don't particularly care for my project) but on modern browsers it works just as planned.

Comment: For future use and visitors the key to "responsive" layouts is the use of "media queries".

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think (like a lot of novice developers) I'd become overly reliant on the Bootstrap framework, rather than learning the reasons why it was able to re-size etc.